# checkbox gets unchecked when the line is drawn

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

`i have few checkboxes in my html code

```
<div id="innerContainer">
    <div style="height:auto;float:left;width:auto;">
        <input type="text"  id="wordone" value="plane" checked="unchecked" readonly/>
        <input type="checkbox" id="one" onclick="testIt();" />
    </div>
    <div style="height:auto;float:left;width:auto;margin-left:80px;">
        <input type="checkbox"  id="mOne" onclick="testIt();" />
        <input style="width:400px;" type="text" id="meanmOne" value="state of tranquility,security and harmony" readonly/>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="innerContainer">
    <div style="height:auto;float:left;width:auto;">
        <input type="text" id="wordtwo" value="piece" readonly/>
        <input type="checkbox"  id="two" onclick="testIt();"/>
    </div>
    <div style="height:auto;float:left;width:auto;margin-left:80px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="mTwo" onclick="testIt();"/>
        <input style="width:400px;" type="text"  id="meanmTwo" value="a fraction or part of a whole" readonly/>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="innerContainer">
    <div style="height:auto;float:left;width:auto;">
        <input type="text"  id="wordthree" value="passed" readonly/>
        <input type="checkbox" id="three" onclick="testIt();"/>
    </div>
    <div style="height:auto;float:left;width:auto;margin-left:80px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="mThree" onclick="testIt();"/>
        <input style="width:400px;" type="text" id="meanmThree" value="a medieval soldier" readonly/>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="innerContainer">
    <div style="height:auto;float:left;width:auto;">
        <input type="text" id="wordfour" value="peace" readonly/>
        <input type="checkbox" id="four" onclick="testIt();"/>
    </div>
    <div style="height:auto;float:left;width:auto;margin-left:80px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="mFour" onclick="testIt();"/>
        <input style="width:400px;" type="text"  id="meanmFour" value="not fancy or beautiful" readonly/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i have implemented the functionality of drawing line between checkboxes that are checked like we do in matching. the following functions are implemented in javascripts

```
function connect(div1, div2, color, thickness) {
var off1 = getOffset(div1);
var off2 = getOffset(div2);
// bottom right
var x1 = off1.left + off1.width - 1;
var y1 = off1.top + off1.height - 5;
// top right
var x2 = off2.left;
var y2 = off2.top + 5;
// distance
var length = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1) * (x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1) * (y2-y1)));
// center
var cx = ((x1 + x2) / 2) - (length / 2);
var cy = ((y1 + y2) / 2) - (thickness / 2);
// angle
var angle = Math.atan2((y1-y2),(x1-x2))*(180/Math.PI);
// make hr
var htmlLine = "<div style='border-radius:5px;padding:0px; margin:0px; height:"        +       thickness + "px; background-color:" + color + "; line-height:1px;   position:absolute; left:" + cx + "px; top:" + cy + "px; width:" + length + "px; -moz-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -o-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); -ms-transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg); transform:rotate(" + angle + "deg);' />";
//
//alert(htmlLine);

document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine; 
}

function getOffset( el ) {
var _x = 0;
var _y = 0;
var _w = el.offsetWidth|0;
var _h = el.offsetHeight|0;
while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
    _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
    _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
    el = el.offsetParent;
    }
return { top: _y, left: _x, width: _w, height: _h };
    }



window.testIt = function() {
var div1;
var div2;

if(document.getElementById('one').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('one');}
else if(document.getElementById('two').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('two');}
else if(document.getElementById('three').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('three');}
else if(document.getElementById('four').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('four');}
else if(document.getElementById('five').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('five');}
else if(document.getElementById('six').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('six');}
else if(document.getElementById('seven').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('seven');}
else if(document.getElementById('eight').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('eight');}
else if(document.getElementById('nine').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('nine');}
else if(document.getElementById('ten').checked)
    {div1 = document.getElementById('ten');}


if(document.getElementById('mOne').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mOne');}   
else if(document.getElementById('mTwo').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mTwo');}
else if(document.getElementById('mThree').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mThree');}
else if(document.getElementById('mFour').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mFour');}
else if(document.getElementById('mFive').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mFive');}
else if(document.getElementById('mSix').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mSix');}
else if(document.getElementById('mSeven').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mSeven');}
else if(document.getElementById('mEight').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mEight');}
else if(document.getElementById('mNine').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mNine');}
else if(document.getElementById('mTen').checked)
    {div2 = document.getElementById('mTen');}

connect(div1, div2, "#000000", 2);
```

}

now when i select the two checkboxes one from left and one from right , both of them gets unchecked after the line is drawn, can some one help me in this and secondly i also want to call a function when the checked checkbox is unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the line: `document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine;`

In this line, the markup in the document body is removed and added again. This causes the checkbox to lose their individual `checked` states. In order to handle this, you'll need to save the states before updating the DOM & then re-apply them to each checkbox.

[**Here's a demo for you**](http://jsfiddle.net/5k4w9/)

And, here's the code that does the trick:

```
cb = [], states = [];
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxes[i].type === 'checkbox') {
          cb.push(checkboxes[i].id);
          states.push(checkboxes[i].checked);
      }
  }

document.body.innerHTML += htmlLine;


var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById(cb[i]).checked = states[i];
  }
```

**EDIT:**

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/5k4w9/1/)

Check the if-else conditions in the code. I've resolved the issue for you.

Comment: but there is a problem , the line is not drawn for other checkboxes

Comment: The line is being drawn. The problem now that the checkboxes are retaining the checked state is that your code always sends the first 2 checked, checkboxes to the `connect` function & an identical line gets overdrawn on top of the existing one. You'll need to figure out the last 2 checkboxes that were checked and accordingly call the `connect` method. Fix the part with numerous `if-else` conditions.

Comment: i added these two lines in connect function div1 =null and div2 = null and remove your modification from the connect function then its works fine and if i added your code to it,it only take the first checkbox

Comment: Since you removed my code, the bug of all checkboxes getting cleared came back and hence your if-else conditions started working. This is because you only check for the first 2 checkboxes that are checked. If all checkboxes get cleared every single time then obviously the code that draws the line will work. But, my code retains the checked state of the checkboxes hence your code failed. I cannot explain further. I've updated my answer with an **Updated demo** link. It is working as expected. Look at the `if-else` conditions and try to understand what was going wrong.